# Issues computing a directional derivative

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I am trying to do a problem which wants me to compute the directional derivatives at $(0, 0)$ of $$f(x, y) = \frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}, \quad f(0, 0) = 0.$$

There are two equations I know for computing the directional derivative, and them seem to be inconsistent for some reason.

Here are the two formulas I have for directional derivatives, $(a, b)$ a unit vector
$$D_{(a, b)}f(x, y) = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(x + ta, y + tb) - f(x, y)}{t}.$$

$$D_{(a, b)}f(x, y) = aD_xf(x, y) + bD_yf(x, y).$$
where $D_x$ and $D_y$ are the partial derivatives.

Computing the partials derivatives I get
$$D_x(0, 0) = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(t, 0) - f(0, 0)}{t} 
= \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\displaystyle\frac{t\cdot 0}{\sqrt{t^2 + 0^2}} - 0}{t} = 0$$

$$D_y(x, 0) = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(0, t) - f(0, 0)}{t}
= \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\displaystyle\frac{0\cdot t}{\sqrt{0^2 + t^2}} - 0}{t} = 0$$

Which in turn should imply $D_{(a, b)}(0, 0) = a\cdot 0 + b\cdot 0 = 0$.

But computing with the limit formula
$$D_{(a, b)}f(x, y) = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(ta, tb) - f(0, 0)}{t}
= \lim_{t \to 0}\frac{\displaystyle\frac{(ta)(tb)}{\sqrt{(ta)^2 + (tb)^2}} - 0}{t} = \lim_{t \to 0}\frac{t^2 ab}{t^2\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}} = \frac{ab}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}} = ab \neq 0$$
if $a \neq 0$ and $b \neq 0$.

I imagine I am doing something silly, or I have a formula wrong or something. But I haven't been able to correct myself yet. Can anyone tell me where my reasoning is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $u=(a,b) \ne 0$ and $t \ne 0$ one has
$$
\frac{f(0+tu)-f(0)}{t}=\frac{f(tu)}{t}=\frac{t^2ab}{t\sqrt{t^2(a^2+b^2)}}=\frac{t}{|t|}f(u).
$$
If $ab=0$, then $D_uf(0)=0$. If $ab \ne 0$, since the limit of $t/|t|$ as $t$ tends to 0 doesn't exist, then the directional derivative does not exist.

Comment: Ah thank you, that clarifies where my issue was. $\sqrt{t^2} = |t|$.

Answer (score 2):

The directional derivatives exist but this function "puckers" at the origin. The actual derivative does not exist. Since it's homogeneous of degree 0, it cannot be continuous at the origin.

Comment: So when the derivative doesn't exist the second formula, $D_{(a, b)}(x, y) = aD_x(x, y) + bD_y(x, y)$ is not correct? I believe that is the one that uses differentiability to derive.

Comment: If the derivative does not exist, you can't write $D_{(a,b)}(x,y)$, 'cause it does not exist.

Comment: Well certainly it still exists in the case where $(a, b) = (1, 0)$ and $(a, b) = (0, 1)$ since those just coincide with $D_x$ and $D_y$.

Comment: Antecedent problem. All of the directional derivatives exist but the function is discontinuous at the origin. This is a classic counterexample.